# load data from database to another one using java

Tags: java, mysql

I have an old database and i want to load the new data from that database every hour into a new database (That i created) using a java code..

i tested that just in two simple databases using this code but it doesn't work for me , can any of u help me or give me some ideas:

```
    import java.sql.*;
class DB{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            //loading the jdbc driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            // Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/b", "root", "");

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            //int rows = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO b.table2 SELECT * FROM a.table1");
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("INSERT INTO b.table2 SELECT * FROM a.table1");

            while (rs.next())
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "  " + rs.getString(2) + "  " + rs.getString(3) + " " + rs.getString(4));
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Insert ... select ... does not return any results, since it is an insert statement.

Comment: it should insert the data from table1 in database a into the table2 in database b

Answer (score 0):

Your code as printed will work fine. INSERT statements do not return a resultset; they return a single number that represents how many rows were affected. Your commented out code is therefore correct; your uncommented line (using `.executeQuery`) isn't useful here and probably won't work.